# How to nest a filter function within another filter function on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, google-sheets-formula

I have searched the forum for this answer but unfortunately could not find it.

Suppose that I have the following database:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeFPv.png)

I want to filter the fund name that has "CDI" as a benchmark and among this group the one that has the largest fee.

Considering this condition, my expected result would be: "N".

To get to this result I tried to use the following code:

=FILTER(A2:A25,B2:B25="CDI",C2:C25=max(C2:C25))

The problem is that this code is returning #N/A to me. Indicating that my filtering criteria has no returns.

This happens because the code is calculating the maximum fee amount out of the the entire database and, in this case, the funds that have the max fees are A,B and R, which does not have CDI as a benchmark.

I could solve it using a two nested filter functions, divided in two steps, as follows:

1st step: I filter all the data that has CDI as a benchmark
2nd step: Out of the data selected in the first step, i filter the one that has the max fee

Unfortunately I couldn't find a example that uses a nested filter function. I also tried to use the Query function but could not get the desired outcome as well.

Please, anyone can help me with this doubt? I am certain that there is an easier way to solve it.

Thank you so much for your time and attention.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Testa aí João:

`=query(A2:C25;"select B, max(C) where B='CDI' group by B")`

abraço.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=FILTER(A2:A25, B2:B25="CDI", C2:C25=MAX(FILTER(C2:C25, B2:B25="CDI")))
```